# page() is not defined error message

Tags: javascript

I am getting a `page() is not defined` error message from Firebug with the following Javascript. Why?

```
( function() {
    var page = function() {
        var min_central_width = 10;
        function minimumCentralWidth(val) {
            min_central_width = val;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        page().minimumCentralWidth(400);
    });

})();
```

I am still new to Javascript. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `page` isn't returning a value, so `page()` is `undefined`. You would have to write something like this:

```
( function() {
    var page = function() {
        // create an object to return:
        var ret = {};
        // set its properties:
        ret.min_central_width = 10;
        ret.minimumCentralWidth =
            function (val) {
                this.min_central_width = val;
            };
        // return it:
        return ret;
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        page().minimumCentralWidth(400);
    });

})();
```

. . . but the above doesn't really do anything. It creates a new object, and sets the object's `min_central_width` to `400` . . . but it doesn't use the object for anything, so the above doesn't have any meaningful effect. (Is this just because you removed code that wasn't relevant to the question? If so, then never mind. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to replicate the issue with a simple code example.

Answer (score 2):

Even though there's some good answers here, I'd like to add a few more to provide some possible options depending on what you're doing.

If you truly want to make minimumCentralWidth a property of a Page class, you can do this:

```
( function() {
    var page = function() {
        var min_central_width = 10;
        this.minimumCentralWidth = function (val) {
            min_central_width = val;
            alert('set to ' + val);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var p = new page(); //new up your object
        p.minimumCentralWidth(400);
    });

})();
```

If you're trying to emulate a static utility class, you can do something like this:

```
( function() {
    var page = new function() { //single instance of your page class
        var min_central_width = 10;
        this.minimumCentralWidth = function (val) {
            min_central_width = val;
            alert('set to ' + val);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        page.minimumCentralWidth(400);
    });

})();
```

Let me know if you have any specific questions on how these examples work, and I'll try to add in some more details!

Comment: Yes, I do have a question. In the first example, does var p = new page(); create a new instance of page just like new in Java? Meaning, if I modify one instance, other instances are not modified?

Comment: Yes, that's quite correct.  Any properties you change in `p` will not affect other instances you've `new`'ed up, since each instance is running within its own closure.